# Show that $A \in GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ if and only if $\det(A) \neq 0$ and $A^{-1} = \det(A)^{-1} B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Where $B = \begin{bmatrix}
  [d] & [-b]  \\
  [-c] & [a]
 \end{bmatrix}$

The way I solved this problem is That I first got all the elements of $M_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ and then considered the elements that have non-zero determinant so this is the elements of $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$, however this approach has depended on the fact that knowing $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$ elements , however I was wondering is there a more direct approach of solving this problem without relying on knowing the elements $GL_2(\mathbb Z_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can show that $AB = BA = \det(A) I$ just by multiplying them out.  Hence if $\det(A) \ne 0$, you have constructed the inverse using the formula given in your title.

To show the converse, use the fact that $\det(UV) = \det(U) \det(V)$.  (It's true for matrices of integers, so it must also be true for matrices of $\mathbb Z_2$.)  Hence $\det(A^{-1}) \det(A) = 1$.

Comment: however I have a question we need to prove that det(A) $\neq $ $0$ for the $\rightarrow$ implication.

Comment: also I don't see how is AB = det(A)I can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: For example AB we have in first entry a1b1 = [a1b1 + a2b3] a1b2 = [a1b2 + a2b4] etc, however when we multiply det(A)I we get something completely different. Could maybe explain a little bit more on those points please ?

Comment: When I multiply out $AB$, I get $\begin{bmatrix} [ad-bc] & 0 \\ 0 & [ad-bc] \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Also, if there is something that multiplied by $\det(A)$  is $1$, then we must have $\det(A) \ne 0$.  If $\det(A) = 0$, we must have $\det(A) \det(A^{-1}) = 0$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Never mind I understand now..

Comment: I see okay I understand everything fully now thank you for your answer !!

Comment: I guess their is also 1 step missing is we have to also check AB = det(A)I = BA and then we now have constructed the inverse.

Comment: Yes, you do have to show that both $AB$ and $BA$ are $\det(A) I$.  Internally I was remembering that for any finite dimensional matrix over a field it has a left inverse if and only if it has a right inverse.  But that is non-trivial, and it is easier to also multiply out $BA$.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: Stephen Montgomery-Smith could you explain a bit for the converse I don't understand the converse... ?

Comment: how come if we know that determinant $det(A^-1)det(A) = 1 = det(A^-1 * A) = det(A*A^-1)$

Comment: Then this will will imply that is in $Gl_2(Z_3)$ ?

Comment: The formula $\det(UV) = \det(U) \det(V)$ is true for $n\times n$ matrices over any commutative ring.  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1159738/showing-that-detab-det-a-det-b-with-the-following-identity/1159781#1159781

Comment: Yes, this proof will show that for $2\times2$ matrices over any commutative ring, a matrix is invertible if and only if its determinant is invertible.

Comment: The result is also true for $n \times n$ matrices.  In place of the matrix $B$, use the Adjugate matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix

Comment: I see I thought in general it wouldn't be true but yeh this makes sense thanks again!